# Configure static IP scope via nmcli

Tags: nmcli

Like it was written [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1397700) by [MCFurry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1397700/configure-static-ip-scope-via-nmcli#:%7E:text=at%2017%3A14-,MCFurry,-111) I haven't been able to find a way to configure `scope link` using nmcli.

> I'm trying to setup a network bridge on a server using nmcli. The
> bridge should have multiple configured static IP addresses with a
> `scope link`.
>
> This is easily done via `ip` command like so: `ip addr add 192.168.0.150/24 dev br0 scope link`
>
> But I can't seem to find how to do this using nmcli only? Adding a
> static IP goes like this:
>
> `nmcli connection modify br0 ipv4.addresses '192.168.0.150/24'`
>
> But how should I configure the scope here?

Has anybody found a way?

Comment: According to your interface name, may be you have a bridge, Before you, a program set a bridge, such as firewall, or `Virtualbox`,  or `VmWare Workstation`. Refer to them.

Comment: In fact you can create by hand the bridge between network namespaces. The question is about `scope link` in `nmcli`. Not sure how `VMWare` or `Virtualbox` guys could help.